# Can Savon allow redirects? 302 "Error"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, soap, savon

Is it possible to make Savon allow redirects? I am currently receiving a 302 HTTP Error, but in reality this should just be a redirect instead of an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Savon uses httpi for the connection. httpi itself is a wrapper around curb, em_http, excon, httpclient, net_http and rack.

The file `em_http.rb` contains the comment that

```
automatic redirect following
```

is **not supported by httpi**.
So what I would try to send the call to the redirection target right away if that's possible.

To find the "real" URL you can use a tool like `curl`, for example:

```
curl -I www.yahoo.in
```

gives you

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 18 Aug 2016 18:50:05 GMT
...
Cache-Control: max-age=3600, public
Location: http://in.yahoo.com/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Age: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Server: ATS
```

The `Location:` key shows the address you want to try next. You might get another redirect. You'll have to try until the `200 OK` is returned.

Comment: How does one figure out the redirect url from the savon request?

Comment: I think I used `curl -v`

Comment: @Steffen Roller Hi Steffen I am getting this error could you please help me how to resolve this.

Comment: I added some explanation how to get there.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup Savon to follow redirect setting up follow_redirects option to true.

```
Eg: client = Savon.client(wsdl: url, ssl_verify_mode: :none, follow_redirects: true)
```

Found here: https://github.com/savonrb/savon/issues/243